# Arabic and latin characters get mixed up

Tags: html, css

I am currently doing the technical part of creating an Arabic version of our website. The other languages should not be affected by this, so basically the changes to the markup must be minimal.

What I have (in English):

```
<div class="location_description"> <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AdministrativeArea">
<span class="glyph featcl_T"></span>
<span itemprop="name">Canton of Obwalden</span>,</span>
<span class="coords" itemprop="geo" itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates">46.77°N 8.43°E 3238m asl
    <meta itemprop="elevation" content="3238">
    <a target="_blank" title="Geonames" href="http://www.geonames.org/2658357"><span class="glyph edit">
</span>
    </a>
    <meta itemprop="latitude" content="46.77">
    <meta itemprop="longitude" content="8.43">
    </span>
</div>
```

"Canton of Obwalden" comes from a database, and can be Arabic too, but can also be in any other language.
Our translator did the translations for "N", "E" and "m asl", and the result is a total mess... http://jsfiddle.net/stby04/xzj5czb5/

So, how do I bring that in the correct order for every possible combination of languages?

Comment: you say it is a total mess, but what layout do you actually expect? you're marking it as rtl after all.

Comment: Well, in English it is administrative area -> latitude and "°N", longitude and "°E", altitude and "m asl". After all I learned about the Arabic language I would hope for (read from left to right) altitude and "متر فوق سطح البح", longitude and "°ق", latitude and "°ش", administrative area. But instead, I have the administrative area (Kanton Obwalden) between the coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add dir="rtl" in every tag in which you expect to have Right to Left Text

```
div class="arabic">
    <div class="location_description"> <span dir="rtl" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AdministrativeArea">

                            <span dir="rtl" class="glyph featcl_T"></span>
 <span dir="rtl" class="arabic" itemprop="name">Kanton Obwalden</span>,</span> <span class="arabic" itemprop="geo" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates">46.77°ش 8.43°ق 3238متر فوق سطح البحر<meta itemprop="elevation" content="3238"><a target="_blank" title="Geonames" href="http://www.geonames.org/2658357"><span class="glyph edit"></span>
        </a>
        <meta itemprop="latitude" content="46.77">
        <meta itemprop="longitude" content="8.43">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will convert it to a CSS only solution, but apart from that your idea is working for me. Thanks a lot!